# If we have points uniformly distributed over the volume of a sphere, what is the distribution of their x coordinate?

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

My understanding is that if we just have points uniformly distributed on the *surface* then they’re uniformly distributed along any given axis, struggling to generalise to the volume case though

Comment: You say *My understanding is that if we just have points uniformly distributed on the *surface* then they’re uniformly distributed along any given axis*. This is not true as the density of points at a point of the axis is proportional to the size of the circle obtained by intersecting the sphere with the plane orthogonal to the axis at the given point. And the size of this circle depends on   the position of the point on the axis.

Comment: Ah of course, sorry! I think I was mistakenly generalising from the 2D case? But in any case do you know the solution for when the points are being generated within the sphere?

Answer (score 1):

For points uniformly distributed over the volume, and $x \in [-R,R]$ on the axis, the distribution will be proportional to $a (R^2-x^2)$where $a$ is a constant to be computed based on the total density of points in the volume of the sphere.

The idea is that the density of points is proportional to the area of the disk obtained by intersecting the volume of the sphere and the plane orthogonal to the axis at the given point. And the radius of the disk is given by Pythagore’s theorem.

Comment: could you provide a proof of that

Comment: See additional point in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is intended to be a comment not an answer ... but again ... wanted to add graphics ... if you run a Monte Carlo (in this case 10000 points) and keep only those within a certain radius, histogram of x-coordinate looks as follows
$$ $$[image]

in this case x-, y- and z-coordinates were randomly generated in [0,1] and then only those within radius $\frac{1}{2}$ of $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ were retained ...
again ... not intended to be an answer